# Serialization of an object within an object in Android?

Tags: java, android, object, serialization

Sorry in advance if this is a stupidly simple question! Part of an app I'm making requires a "character sheet" object that holds different stat objects to be saved via serialization.

What I'm concerned about is if the values within the stat objects will be properly saved when I serialize the character sheet object? If the stat objects won't save right during serialization is there a process anyone can recommend to make it work properly?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That should work. why don't you just try it? serialize and then deserialize, and see the results.

Comment: are these "stat objects" (whetever it may be) serializable?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the serialization yourself.

There are two options:

1. Custom serialization

This is achieved by adding these optional serialization methods to your class:

- `private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException`
- `private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException`
- `private void readObjectNoData() throws ObjectStreamException`

See [the Serializable API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) for details.

2. `Externalizable`

Using `Externalizable` instead of `Serializable`. This way you have total control of how your class is serialized.

In this case, you need to implement these two methods from the interface:

- `readExternal(ObjectInput in)`
- `writeExternal(ObjectOutput out)`

See [the Externalizable API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) for details.